# How to convert the pixel values that are stored in a cell back to an image using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have extracted 9 pixels of a 3 x 3 matrix from a 512 x 512 image.I have store these pixel values in a cell to do my calculations.Now i want to convert these calculated pixel values back into an image.So what should i do to convert into an image? Is it possible to convert cell into an image or should i store my pixel values in some other form to convert them into an image.If so how should i do that?

Comment: you should try and figure it out yourself first, only then come here and ask concrete questions.

Comment: @Abinaya why do you store them in a cell? wouldn't it be easier to store them in an array to make the calculations easier?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'convert into an image'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [imagesc()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) function. You will need to convert your cell back to matrix using cell2mat or you could store the values in a matrix to begin with.